# float precision visual basic

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel, floating-point

I would like to know how to get more digits in visual basic while calculating pi. This is my code:

```
    Dim enne, phi As Double
    phi = 1
    Console.WriteLine("Insert numble of cycles")
    enne = Console.ReadLine
    For i = 0 To enne
        phi = 6 + ((2 * enne + 1) * (2 * enne + 1)) / phi
        enne = enne - 1
    Next
    phi = phi - 3

    Console.WriteLine("pi is")
    Console.WriteLine(phi)
    Console.WriteLine("normal pi is ")
    Console.WriteLine(Math.PI)
```

Comment: More digits than how many? Double has a [precision of 15 digits](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz.aspx). If you need more, the numeric types are not going to cut it and you'll need specialized libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The question was marked as VBA when I wrote this answer.**

Using the Decimal subvariant type you can get much more precision.

This takes a little while to run...

```
Sub Pi()

    Dim enne As Variant, phi As Variant
    phi = CDec(1)

    enne = 100000000

    For i = 0 To enne
        phi = 6 + ((2 * enne + 1) * (2 * enne + 1)) / phi
        enne = enne - 1
    Next
    phi = phi - 3

    Debug.Print " 3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716"
    Debug.Print phi

End Sub
```

Actual PI here: http://www.piday.org/million/

Answer (score 0):

VBA can't handle numbers with a better precision than double, if you want more you have to work around with strings. The xNumbers add-in can do this trick, you can find an updated xlam version here: http://www.thetropicalevents.com/Xnumbers60.htm

Comment: Not entirely true. Please see my answer. The decimal data subtype of the variant will bring more precision than the double, But beyond that strings are indeed required.

Answer (score 0):

Look into .Net's BigInteger library. You will have to adapt your algorithm a bit. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx. It uses methods to perform operations such as subtraction and division.